# Maximum $n$ such that $e2^{1 - {k \choose 2}}{k \choose 2}{{n-2} \choose {k-2}} \leq 1$, as $k \to \infty$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, asymptotics, approximation-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Using:

- ${k \choose 2} \leq \frac{k^2}{2}$, and
- ${{n-2} \choose {k-2}} \leq \frac{k^2}{n^2}{n \choose k} \leq \frac{k^2}{n^2} \left(\frac{ne}{k}\right)^k$,

we have $e2^{1 - {k \choose 2}}{k \choose 2}{{n-2} \choose {k-2}} \leq 
\frac{e2^{-{k \choose 2}}k^4}{n^2} \left( \frac{ne}{k} \right)^k =
\frac{ek^4}{n^2} \left( \frac{ne \sqrt2}{k{\sqrt2}^k} \right) ^k$.

If $n=\frac{1}{e \sqrt{2}} k \sqrt{2}^{k},$ the parenthetical term is 1. The leading coefficient is then $e^{2} k^{2} 2^{1-k}$.

Now the text I'm reading says that we can afford for the parenthetical term to be $2 + o(1)$, and so we can take $ n=\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{e}+o(1)\right) k \sqrt{2}^{k}$. Can I get an explanation of these last two assertions?

Comment: Which limit is implied in this $o(1)$ expression you write? $n \to \infty$ or $k \to \infty$ or some simultaneous limit of both? (It sounds like it is the latter, specifically taking $n=n(k)$ and then sending $k \to \infty$.)

Comment: Apologize for the lack of information. We are considering $k \to \infty$. I will add this into the question.

Comment: That's simple enough: the factor on the outside is going to zero more or less like $2^{-k}$, so it is OK for the parenthetical term to grow like $(2-\epsilon)^k$. Checking whether it can grow like $2^k$, or $(2-f(k))^k$ for some $f(k)>0$ going to zero, requires examining the polynomial factors.

Comment: Thanks. Just realized I was mistakenly thinking of "the parenthetical term" as including that "to the power of $k$". And also, I take it here the author means the $o(1)$ can be negative?

Comment: As I said, you have to play with the factors to see how much smaller than 2 the parenthetical term needs to be in order for the whole thing to stay less than 1 as $k \to \infty$. In particular, if the parenthetical term is just 2, then it's not good enough because the effect of the outside will lead to polynomial growth ($n$ only kills two factors of $k$ so two more survive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression looks like some sort of Ramsey Theory construction. The goal is to find the largest $n = n(k)$ such that the inequality holds in the limit $k \to \infty$, I presume.

Suppose that in $n = \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{e} + o(1)\right) k \sqrt{2}^k$, we take the $o(1)$ term to be say, $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{ek}$, forcing the parenthetical term to be, $2 - 2/\sqrt{k}$. Then the exponential term is now
$$\left(2 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{k}}\right)^k = 2^k \left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)^k \sim 2^k e^{-\sqrt{k}}$$
Note that the factor of $2^{-k}$ brought about by the factor of $1/n^2$ outside the exponent will cancel the $2^k$ from the exponent, and asymptotically the expression will grow like $k^2 e^{-\sqrt{k}}$, which is certainly $o(1)$.

The idea is that if the exponential term grows slow enough than $2^k$, then the factor of $1/n^2$ can cancel this growth as it has a factor of $2^{-k}$. In the above example, we've shown that this can be obtained by having the base of the exponent to be $2 - o(1)$.

Comment: I get the general idea. But I tried substituting $o(1)$ with the function that you'd chosen just to be sure, and could only get $n = \frac{(k+1)\sqrt2^{k+1}}{e}$, and hence the exponential term would be $2^k \left( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right)^k$.

Comment: And yes this is part of a probabilistic proof for the statement that $R(k) \geq \left( \frac{\sqrt2}{e} + o(1) \right) k \sqrt2^k$ as $k \to \infty$.

Comment: The $o(1)$ term is negative.